# How to run bash code inside netcat connection

Tags: bash, netcat

So i have a problem : i want to run bash commands when i connect to a server. I have to capture the flag when i connect to a server X via port Y, it stays open only 5-10 sec then closes and you need to guess the random number from 1 to 1000. The for is not the problem (for i in {1..1000} echo $i), the problem is how i make the netcat wait until the connection is done and then run a command. I searched on stackoverflow and a lot of websites and it is not what i need.

```
while ! nc server port; do   
  sleep 0.1
done
```

and somwhere here run the command but if you run it over the while, it will run when the netcat is closed

Comment: Are you writing a netcat client that sends numbers to a server? Or are you writing a server that reads numbers from a client? Or both? You say you have to capture a flag - what flag, where from?

Comment: it was a competition online, only a client, you connect to the server like : nc ip port, then it will output what you need to do, you don't know how it's made, but you need to "break" it and get the flag by exploiting some vulnerabilities or in this case some code. I found this while searching more : for ((i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)); do echo "$i"; done | nc server port